# McKay/Carter Intergalactic Gate Bridge name reference to real world

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1, stargate-atlantis, inspiration, names

It seems likely to me that the McKay/Carter Intergalactic Gate Bridge is a reference to the Macdonald-Cartier Bridge or Freeway given the similarity in name and the show's Canadian connection.

See:

- [McKay/Carter Intergalactic Gate Bridge](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/McKay/Carter_Intergalactic_Gate_Bridge) (Stargate Wiki),
- [Macdonald-Cartier Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macdonald-Cartier_Bridge) (Wikipedia),
- [Macdonald–Cartier Freeway, aka Ontario Highway 401](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macdonald-Cartier_Freeway) (Wikipedia).

TL,DR:  The Macdonald-Cartier Bridge and the Macdonald-Cartier Freeway represent connections between Ontario and Quebec (i.e. "English Canada" and "French Canada" -- I assume this was part of the inspiration for the names), not unlike the McKay/Carter Bridge is a connection between the Pegasus and Milky Way Galaxies.

Any direct evidence of this?

Comment: Don't you go dissing the 401!  :) Comparing a mere intergalactic bridge to the mighty 401!  The noive I say, the noive!  Why, I otta...

Comment: And this makes we want to ask if there is any Sir John A. Macdonald / Sir George-Étienne Cartier shipper fanfic out there ?   (But I won't!)

Comment: Any reference to actual persons, places or events is purely coincidental...

Comment: Note that Martin Gero says [Great question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/105503/3823) so the Word of God is you must upvote.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Why your hypothesis *might* be correct...

There are some coincidences that add some more fuel to your hypothesis, namely:

- the Mckay-Carter Intergalactic Bridge made its first appearance in *Stargate: Atlantis* "The Return" Part 1, which was written by **Martin Gero**, a Swiss-born Canadian (who wrote many episodes for the show)
- the Macdonald-Cartier Bridge is in Ottawa (or Ottawa and Gatineau, if you like) and Gero [went to high shool](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1236625/bio?ref_=nm_ov_bio_sm) in Ottawa

Of course, the characters of Rodney McKay and Samantha Carter already existed in the show, but it certainly plausible that Gero took advantage of these in order to slip in a reference to something Canadian.

Now for the bad news.

## Why your hypothesis is incorrect...

**Because Martin Gero says so.**

> **@martingero:** Hey, love your work! Curious: was the McKay-Carter Intergalactic Bridge a reference to the Macdonald-Cartier Bridge?
>
> **@RemnantOfPraxis:** Great question and: no.

([Source](https://twitter.com/RemnantOfPraxis/status/656482648882311176))

The consolation prize is that he likes your question.

Comment: [To Twitter](https://twitter.com/martingero)??

Comment: @ThePopMachine : It shall be done. :-)

Comment: @ThePopMachine : See update --- sorry to be the bearer of bad news.

Comment: oh well.   It still is in my mind.

Comment: @ThePopMachine : I'm happy to continue believing it as well, but don't let the truth drive a wedge between this answer and its green checkmark. ;-)

Comment: Checkmark whore.  I guess there's no question this is the correct answer.

Comment: @ThePopMachine : Rep is fine, but checkmarks are divine. :-)

Comment: Or, I could withhold it just to bug you.

Answer (score 1):

Impossible to know without a statement from the writers/producers (maybe on a DVD commentry).
Probably just named after the 2 lead scientists in the show with McKay getting top billing because it was introduced in Atlantis.